# how to access the solution values for all variables which are in a matrix form?

Tags: c++, matrix, cplex

*(Note: this question relates to [IBM's ILOG CPLEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPLEX) C++ API, documentation for which circa 2007 is in a pdf via HTTP [here](http://www-eio.upc.es/lceio/manuals/cplex-11/pdf/refcppcplex.pdf), and current materials for "version 12" available [via IBM's FTP](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/websphere/ilog/docs/optimization/cplex/))*

I have a matrix variable and I want to transfer their values to a matrix parameter.
This is what I did:

```
typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> NumMatrix;
typedef IloArray<IloBoolVarArray> BoolVarMatrix;

NumMatrix ystar(env,I);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
    ystar[i] = IloNumArray(env, T);
}

BoolVarMatrix y(env,I);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
    y[i] = IloBoolVarArray(env, T);
}

for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++)
    cplex_master.getValues(ystar[i],y[i]);
```

But apparently `getValues()` only works with `IloNumVarArray`. How can I fix this?

Comment: We don't know what any of those types are so can't really answer without guessing.

Comment: @awoodland: did you mean typedef?

Comment: Not exactly. The `typedef`s remove one level of confusion, but now we still don't know what `cplex_master` is. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) talks about the details that make a question easy to answer without lots of guessing.

Comment: but that's just the name I've given to my solver, how is that important?

Comment: @awoodland's point is more that just because someone is familiar with C++ they don't necessarily know anything about this particular matrix solver API...which seems relatively obscure.  That would be like presuming someone would be familiar with the poetry of William Lisle Bowles just because they speak English.  *(Who's that, you ask?  My point exactly!)*  There are 35 other questions with the CPLEX tag though, and 13 people watching it...so it's not hopeless to ask here.  I added an API doc link to help.  But you might need a more specialized forum for help with this sort of question.

Comment: Even for people who know what the library you're using is and can guess at the missing details if you write something can be passed through a compiler when I've got 5 minutes spare I'm likely to give it a go. Making your questions easier to answer will directly result in you getting more, better answers faster.

Comment: Those are good tips for improving this question, but it's also important to remember that the OP doesn't *have to* ask a broader, easier to answer question. This fits in perfectly well with the guidelines and *some people* might be able to answer it. If not, then it will go unanswered. But it's not very fruitful to harp on FAQ/Guideline-abiding questions. If *you* don't know how to answer it (even if that is the OP's fault for asking a terse, overly specific question) then probably best practices are to just ignore that question. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IloCplex::getValue can be used for any IloNumVar.  The return value is just a double, so you aren't restricted to the Concert data structures.  The expression y[i][t] gives you an IloNumVar.

```
   for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++)
        for (IloInt t = 0; t < T; ++t)
        ystar[i][t] = cplex_master.getValue(y[i][t]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing game time!  :-)  I'm going to just guess that `cplex_master` is of type `IloCplex`.

You have two freshly initialized 2-dimensional matrices, one of "boolean variables" and the other of "non-variable floating point numbers".  It would appear you want to solve the boolean variables in `y` and have the results represented as floating point numbers in `ystar`.

1. I'm not sure what solving blank matrices into each other accomplishes, so I'll just pretend they're not blank in your actual code
2. I don't know what your scenario is transforming boolean matrices row-wise into floats, but maybe that's legitimate somehow

Anyway, `IloCplex` offers four variants of `getValues()`, all of which seem to operate on the two parameters which it names *var* and *val*:

```
public void getValues(const IloIntVarArray var, IloNumArray val) const
public void getValues(IloNumArray val, const IloIntVarArray var) const
public void getValues(const IloNumVarArray var, IloNumArray val) const
public void getValues(IloNumArray val, const IloNumVarArray var) const
```

They all have similar documentation which is to the effect of:

> This method puts the solution values of the integer variables speciﬁed by the array var
>   into the array val. Array val is resized to the same size as  array var, and val[i]
>   will contain the solution value for variable var[i].

There's an unusual design choice, in that *val* is being modified despite the fact that it is being passed by value.  This is very non-C++ style.  If you were dealing with integers, say, and wrote code like:

```
void myCopy(const int source, int destination) {
    /* what could go here? */
}

void someFunction() {
   int a = 10;
   int b;
   myCopy(a, b);
}
```

...there is no way to write the `myCopy()` routine with that prototype.  The destination was passed by value so `myCopy()` can't reach back and change the value of `b` in the caller.  Proper C++ would do it by using pointers or references (via `&`):

```
void myCopy(const int source, int& destination) {
    destination = source;
}
```

So this CPLEX C++ thing uses some kind of trick under the hood, I'd assume through that mysterious `env` parameter...to do things another way.  It suffers from the typical case of what happens when people write weird language wrappers and don't know the idioms.  Another post has been very critical here:

[Is it just me or could the Cplex Concert API use some improvements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443195/is-it-just-me-or-could-the-cplex-concert-api-use-some-improvements)

Your question might be why the `IloCplex` doesn't take `IloBoolVarArray` as a *var* and an `IloNumArray` *val*, when it would be happy to take a `IloIntVarArray` as a *var* and an `IloNumArray` *val*.  After all, `IloBoolVarArray` inherits from `IloIntVarArray`...shouldn't it be able to be used in the same slot?

But these pass-by-value semantics of the `getValue()` method inhibits the natural inheritance that might otherwise have worked.  You can only pass derived classes in lieu of a base class when passing by pointer or reference.  So no go on this.

If you really want to use an `IloBoolVarArray` instead of an `IloIntVarArray`, then I'd guess you'd have to go through an intermediate:

```
typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> NumMatrix;
typedef IloArray<IloBoolVarArray> BoolVarMatrix;
typedef IloArray<IloIntVarArray> IntVarMatrix;

NumMatrix ystar(env,I);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
    ystar[i] = IloNumArray(env, T);
}

BoolVarMatrix y(env,I);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
    y[i] = IloBoolVarArray(env, T);
}

IntVarMatrix yint(env,I);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
    for(IloInt t = 0; t < T; t++) {
        yint[i][t] = y[i][t];
    }
}

for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++)
    cplex_master.getValues(ystar[i],yint[i]);
```

The real question might be if using `IloBool` vs. `IloInt` is really worth it.  It looks like an afterthought:

> This type deﬁnition represents Boolean values in Concert Technology. Those values are
>   IloTrue and IloFalse. Booleans are, in fact, integers of type IloInt.
>   IloFalse is 0 (zero),  and IloTrue is 1 (one). This type anticipates the built-in
>   bool type proposed for standard C++. By using this type, you  can be sure that the
>   Concert Technology components of your application will port in this respect without
>   source changes across different hardware  platforms.

The arrays don't seem to have first-class treatment in solvers, but individual variables do:

> An instance of IloBoolVar is extracted by IloSolver  (documented in the ILOG
>   Solver Reference Manual)  as an instance of the class IlcBoolVar  (also documented
>   in the ILOG Solver Reference Manual).
>
> An instance of IloBoolVar is extracted by IloCplex  (documented in the ILOG
>   CPLEX Reference Manual)  as a column representing a  numeric variable of type Bool
>   with bounds as speciﬁed by IloBoolVar

I'd imagine avoiding it entirely is the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I got an idea from your comment and fixed it more easily! I just needed to change the type of `bool` to `int` and give it `0,1` bounds.